# How to change class of parent element from focus/blur?

Tags: angularjs, events, focus, parent, blur

I'm trying to add a class to the parent of an input when it gets focus. I can get the parent, but I can't seem to set the classname. Here's what I tried in this plunkr:

http://plnkr.co/edit/eEfSeDb7i3uujjBZt21z?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html id="ng-app" ng-app="app"> <!-- id="ng-app" IE<8 -->

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://nervgh.github.io/css/animate.min.css" />    
    <style>
        .highlight {
          border: 2px solid red;
        }
        .blue-border
        {
          border:2px solid blue;
        }
    </style>

     <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>    
    <script>
        angular.module( 'app', [])
            .run( function( $rootScope, $timeout ) {                   

                 $rootScope.focusInput= function($event )
                {
                    angular.element($event.target).parent().className += " " + 'highlight';
                    console.log( angular.element($event.target).parent() );
                };

                $rootScope.blurInput= function($event )
                {
                    angular.element($event.target).parent().className.replace(' highlight', '');                                       
                };
            });
    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <div class="blue-border">

      <input ng-focus="focusInput($event)" ng-blur="blurInput($event)" value="Lactobacillus acidophilus"/>  

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Notice how it logs the parent successfully. However, the border does not turn red! Is there some other more "Angulary" way of doing this?

Comment: Hm, well I can set the .css property on the parent, but I can't set the className (it is undefined).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Angular's JQLite provides the 'addClass' and 'removeClass' functions for this:

```
angular.element($event.target).parent().addClass('highlight');
```

See the documentation here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

Comment: A couple things not in favor, the new class should have been after the first one to override, too, so not much would have worked without that, either. :p